# How to copy large data from assets folder to 'app-private/files' folder

Tags: android

I have number of files and folders in my `assets` folder.
How can i copy these files at the fist launch of the application to some different folder inside `app-private/files` folder.

I have found simile questions, but most of the answers are related to looping through all the files and then copying them to destination. But in my case this process is taking time.

Is there any other way by which we can copy files.

Comment: Why are you copying them? Do you need to modify them? If not, just use them straight from assets. Otherwise, maybe you can just copy them on demand, rather than all at once.

Comment: I like what @323go is saying. Copying them on-demand may be your best bet.

Comment: @323go I want to modify/update that files and it is async task it can be done any opint of time/date. so i want to move it to app-private/files.